# Connecting copper strap to grounding rod

Tags: grounding

Is there a way I can connect a 2"x.025" copper strap to a 5/8" grounding rod that can be buried?

I've seen the bolt-on strap clamps, but those need to be inspected periodically. I've also been looking at cadweld one shots, but haven't found any that appear to work with thin strap. Are there any options I'm missing?

Answer (score 5):

There are some suitable connections in the [reusable Cadweld product line](https://www.erico.com/catalog/literature/E524C-ASEN.pdf):

[image]

But you're right, there don't appear to be any similar connections in the One Shot line.

An alternative is brazing. An alloy like [Harris Stay-Silv 15](https://www.harrisproductsgroup.com/en/Products/Alloys/Brazing/Phos-Copper/Stay-Silv-15.aspx) works well. I've managed to make acceptable connections (barely) with a good MAP plumbing torch to ground rods that are not buried yet and 6 AWG wire, but with wider copper strap and/or ground rods that are already buried, you'll need a larger oxyacetylene torch to get the components hot enough.

Answer (score 1):

As Phil Frost mentioned, you can try the MAPP gas and silver brazing rods.  There is a good article which has some suggestions on doing all this, including how to get the materials on a budget (scrap copper roof flashing, for example, instead of expensive strapping). Lowes has a MAPP gas cylinder and torch for about $55.

See [this article](https://topbandhams.com/Tech/Lightning%20Protection-Taming%20Thors%20Thunder-On%20A%20Budget.pdf) for details.  It describes how ham radio operators can use inexpensive materials to create a lightning protection system for their stations that is similar to what a commercial transmtter site would use: how to place ground rods and copper strapping, a description of the (very expensive) Cadweld process and the MAPP gas and silver brazing rod alternative, and building a single point ground along with antenna discharge units, etc. so as to have a station that will survive a lightning hit (something many Amateurs think is impossible but that commercial operators have happen all the time).  If you read it, along with Mike Holt's [Illustrated Guide to the NEC for Radio and TV Equipment](http://file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/Radio_and_Television_2014NEC.pdf), it gives an excellent description of how to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: We discourage answers that are mostly or only links, because links rot.  Would you please edit your answer to include a summary of the article that you linked to?